# Oracle 11g client jars performance impact with Oracle 10g server

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

We are planning to use Oracle 11g client jars with our Oracle server which is using Oracle version 10.2.0.4.

There are already some performance issues which we have seen in the last couple of years due to the huge number of records in our database. Can you tell me if upgrading the client jars to 11g would increase or decrease the performance?

Regards,
Ken

Comment: Which problems do you experience?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the exact version combination of client and server you are planning to use are actually supported. Have a look at metalink document [ID 207303.1] which describes the compatibility matrix.